# What members are exported in GAS library?

Tags: google-apps-script

Suppose I have a global variable and class definition like this:

```
    var config = { url: "google.com" }
    var TestClass = /** @class */ (function () { 
       function TestClass() {}
       TestClass.prototype.method1 = function () { do smth here };
       return TestClass; } ());
```

Would they be available as MyLibrary.config and MyLibrary.TestClass?

I have big library and some of its members are exported, others are not and I want to understand what is the difference

Comment: Can you share more details on it? Can you share the library code and the script calling it? An apps script library when it is added it can have all the functions executed.

Comment: Hi - yes I am sorry, looks like the problem was that list of version was too long and in new version of GAS editor new versions are not displayed. So I just happened to pick old version. To answer the question in subject - looks like all classes are exported, but variables are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export the variables you can refer to [Best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#best_practices) .3:

> Only enumerable global properties are visible to library users. This includes function declarations, variables created outside a function with var, and properties explicitly set on the global object. For example, Object.defineProperty() with enumerable set to false creates a symbol you can use in your library, but this symbol isn't accessible by your users.

So you would have to create those variable as ENUMS